# Create A Custom Event That Can Be Triggered From Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, code-behind

I'm breaking my pick on something I would have thought to be pretty simple.  We have an application which uses some advanced color animations on a panel or a border control to attract the users attention when specific conditions occur.  Usually those conditions are identified by communicating with an external device and could occur at any time.  So I want to be able to define a trigger for a border or stackpanel like I might for it's standard IsEnabled or IsFocused properties but one that I can trigger arbitrarily form the Main Window's code-behind (IsMyArbitraryCondition).  I imagine it would look like this:

```
<Border x:Name="Fancy_Border">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMyArbitraryCondition" Value="true">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Board" Storyboard="{StaticResource ComplicatedAnimation}"/>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Then in the code-behind for the main window:

```
Fancy_Border.IsMyArbitraryCondition = true;
// ComplicatedAnimation occurs
```

I've seen attached properties, dependency properties, etc suggested but my level of knowledge about how to us WPF has been insufficient so far to use those examples successfully.  It seems like there must be a relatively simple way that I can still define my complex trigger behavior with the convenience of an XAML style but have that style trigger fired by something (anything!) other than the built in properties (IsMouseOver, IsPressed, IsVisible, etc etc).

**EDIT (Using UserControl And DataTrigger)**

I have a complete and working example provided below.  The only remaining issue is that I can't put named components *inside* the content of my extended border control.  The compiler returns:

```
Cannot set Name attribute value 'Example' on element 'TextBlock'. 'TextBlock' is under the scope of element 'HighlightBorder', which already had a name registered when it was defined in another scope.
```

This is an issue as I'm not developing using MVVM and seek to directly manipulated some individual controls that are within the HighlightBorder.  Any workarounds you know of for that would be very helpful!

**HighlightBorder.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace App
{
    public partial class HighlightBorder : Border
    {
        public HighlightBorder()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool IsActiveHighlight
        {
            get { return (bool) GetValue(ActiveHighlightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ActiveHighlightProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveHighlightProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsActiveHighlight", typeof(bool), typeof(HighlightBorder), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

**HighlightBorder.xaml**

```
<Border x:Class="App.HighlightBorder"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActiveHighlight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"  Value="true">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="EnabledPulse" Storyboard="{DynamicResource PulseAccent}"/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="EnabledPulse"/>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="EnabledClear" Storyboard="{DynamicResource ClearAccent}"/>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<local:HighlightBorder x:Name="Grouped_Controls">
    <TextBlock> Example Content </TextBlock>
</local:HighlightBorder>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
Grouped_Controls.IsActiveHighlight = false;  // Or true
```

Comment: Without a good [mcve] showing clearly what you're trying to do, and an explanation of exactly what you've tried and what specifically you're having trouble with, a good answer can't be provided. That said, typically in your situation you'd add a property to your view model, and then use `<DataTrigger/>` (not `<Trigger/>`) with a binding to that property. If you don't have a view model then, well...you'd need to fix that problem first.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Peter.  That's a fair point; I've updated my question with a much more complete example of what I'm doing as well as the exact compiler error I'm still getting when attempting to use the custom control.  Still, part of the point of the question was to seek help identifying a simpler and lighter weight solution than what I've shown here (which uses the somewhat "nuclear" option of creating an entirely custom extended control just to get the "effect" of a custom property that can be used to arbitrarily trigger a set of storyboards).

Comment: _"This is an issue as I'm not developing using MVVM and seek to directly manipulated some individual controls that are within the HighlightBorder"_ -- this is your problem right here. WPF is _designed_ with the intent that code will keep a strong separation of concerns between UI and data, using the provided data binding mechanisms.

Comment: Your question is still lacking a proper [mcve], but you may also find lack of responses because of the improper use of the API. No doubt it can be made to work, but the intersection of experienced WPF programmers and people who have an interest in meddling directly with UI objects is very small, and the API itself will seem very uncooperative when used this way.

Comment: With all due respect, though your point about MVVM may be fair (despite that I have seen many discussions among people who do not develop in WPF with that model), what I have provided is _absolutely_ a minimum complete example.  I can go create a blank WPF project in VS right now, at that new user control resource and get exactly the same compilation error.

Comment: _"what I have provided is absolutely a minimum complete example"_ -- That is a patently false statement. There are _many_ ways in which your code fails to meet the **minimal** and **complete** standard, but one need look only at the `MainWindow.cs` block to see how the code is incomplete. A bare, single program statement doesn't in any way meet that standard. You should re-read [mcve], and also read [ask] and especially the articles linked at the bottom of that page. You will not find the help you're seeking until you get over your lack of understanding of what [mcve] actually means.